# Does updating a software update group reset the deadline timer?

Tags: sccm-2012

I have been working with SCCM 2012 setting up a rolling update schedule. I'd prefer to use the option 'add to an existing software update group'.

The issue I have with this is I'm not sure if this would reset the deadline for any updates already included in the existing software update group. It'd be a pain if my timers were reset just because something new is getting added.

Put another way:

Is the deployment schedule / deadline behavior dictated by the individual updates, or is it done based on the software update group as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with this the answer is *yes*, if you edit an existing group it will reset the timer for all the existing updates.